# NNTP client - Java - Download Article is downloaded 3 extra garbage bytes randomly

Tags: java, nntp

I wrote this NNTP client... and I am trying to use it as part of a bigger project, but it seems that the downloadArticle(string msgID) is downloading some extra bytes, but randomly.  For example, one time I will run the application and it will insert 3 garbage bytes after a CR/LF.  I will run the application again and it doesn't download those bytes.  I have isolated the problem and it is not in the yenc decoder etc... it is definitely in this NNTPclient class.

I posted the whole class for completeness.  Code is here:
http://www.pastebin.com/m214131cc

Comment: You really should check all your nntpreader.read() calls. You're reading from a socket, you are not guaranteed to read the no. of bytes you've set as the buffer size.

Comment: why not use the [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/classpathx/javamail/) library?  Or, at least fork it if you don't like it :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of complex and therefore error-prone logic concerning newlines- the error is almost certainly somewhere in there. You also seem to be using an inconsistent (and inconsistently-named mix of In/OutputStreams and Readers/Writers.

The question is: do you actually *need* all that? I'm pretty sure that you don't. All that that class seems to do is write the contents of an InputStream to a file. For that, you do not need to think about newlines (or, indeed, characters) - just transfer the raw bytes via a `byte[]` buffer (or simply use Apache commons-io's [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)) class).

Or if you need to normalize newlines, use [BufferedReader.readLine()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) instead of writing your own, error-prone newline recognition logic.